# How to send massive mail in Window

Tags: email, smtp, email-server, sendmail

I'm looking for a solution that can send massive mail in Windows.
I'm not spaming. My company want to send mail to our user.
I don't want to use third party smtp server(like google mail).
Because it'll ask captcha when sending several mail continuously.
Please suggest me some solution.

**EDIT:**
I only want to send mail in Windows.
Massive only means several hundreds mail per days.
I just want to send our product information to our user.

Comment: You have not really provided enough information to be of any use. Are these internal users in your own company? Are they external users in your own company? Are these customers that require this data? What email system are you trying to use? And finally, ask yourself the question: "Is email the best way to try to send this data?" first

Comment: If you're looking for software to handle the list http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Free_mailing_list_software is a good place to start.  Click around Wikipedia a bit because not all software is listed on that page.

Answer (score 2):

[IIS has an SMTP service.](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/751/configure-smtp-e-mail-in-iis-7-and-above/)

**EDIT:**

I came back to this answer to be of more use. To be sure, the above answer is tongue in cheek.

If you're going to send out massive amounts of email, then you'd better know what you're doing and have some serious protective infrastructure. You need to set up SPF records and use DKIM. You'll want a bank of dedicated IP addresses for your outbound email. You'll need statistics and monitoring that are tracked within your emails to determine who is viewing what and if the email is truly wanted or not. You'll need double-opt in systems and on and on.

In short, if by "massive" you mean "millions of emails per day" or even just "hundreds of thousands per day" you'll need to lay out some serious cash and have some serious skills. You cannot use IIS's SMTP service for this. I repeat, you cannot use IIS for this. There is someone on this site that uses IIS to send hundreds of thousands of emails and it is not pretty. They are constantly black listed. They have a hard time managing it. They are consistently asking questions on ServerFault relating to their woes.

You will need to look into some software like PowerMTA to do all that you require. In fact, what would be better is if you use something like MailChimp or Constant Contact. If you have to send the mail yourself, look into companies like SendGrid or JangoMail that know how to handle outbound mail on a massive scale. Please don't do this yourself unless you have a crack engineering team (or your engineering team is on crack).

Answer (score 2):

This depends a lot on what you're using for email. If it's an internally source solution (Exchange, that kind of thing) it's easier than if it's an outsourced solution (Google Apps).

For the purposes of this question I'm presuming "massive" means "to many people" not "very large mail-sizes". The later is a vastly harder nut to crack.

If it's an internally sourced email solution, there are many programmatic methods for connecting to SMTP servers and sending lots of mail. Since you control the mail-servers you can provide any configuration changes needed to permit such an access pattern. We did much the same at my last job.

If it's an externally sourced email solution, you're at the mercy of the solution provider. Some allow you to have a 'whitelist' IP address from which all mail will be considered clean, some don't. Some have unknowable throttling limits on how much mail you can send, and you'll just have to live within them.